# How do I show the count of certain types of SharePoint List columns?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I would like to know how can I can sum the values of a specific column across multiple rows in a list. For example:

[image]

I have 3 rows of camera entries and 2 rows of keyboard entries. I would like create a new column with the sum of these rows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use 'Group By' to group (and sum) your Keyboard rows and your Camera rows.

Go in List Settings>Modify View>scroll down to 'Group By' and select 'Hardware Type' as the value.

You might also want to use 'Totals'.  Go in List Settings>Modify View>Totals>choose a field to total by e.g. Hardware Type.  You can also use Filters to filter on one Hardware Type if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View with Group and then Sum by column you need.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the solutions which you can implement for getting sum

1. Most easy solution is on the ribbon tab select Modify View. Scroll down and expand Totals section. Select Sum and select the column for which you need to apply sum and save the view. You can use it together with groups.
2. Other solution is to use Calculated columns

https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/sharepoint-calculated-column-total/

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Is there way to create separate column with sum of all Hardware Type?

Comment: Yes indeed this is also found in the Totals section of a view. Simply choose "Count" as your option and it will count the data in any given column. Filtering on your data will cause the number to display the total number of items filtered in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your view and see the Total section to turn the sum option on. (note your column needs to be a number type). you can also group by the other columns to get the sums that are grouped by a specified type.

[image]